# ¿Cómo Acceder Desde PHP al Target #Inicio ( ej. http://www.dos-a-la-tres.com/index.php#Inicio ) Que Tenga en la Dirección de la Página?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo una App en PHP y me gustaría saber cómo puedo acceder al Identificador de Trozo de la Página en cuestión. Quiero Acceder al #Inicio desde PHP Para No Perder el Punto de la Página en Cuestión.
¿Alguien sabe como acceder al Target de la Dirección Desde la Que Vienen?

ejemplo de Dirección. http://www.dos-a-la-tres.com/index.php#Inicio

Tengo este Código Que Me Accede a la Misma Página, Pero No con el Target #Inicio

header('location:' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

Comment: ¿Intentaste agregar `. '#Inicio'` al final de la ubicación?

Comment: Los fragmentos no se transmiten por http. Pero podrías copiarlo en javascript a un parámetro de petición.

Comment: Quiero Que Me lo Ponga de Manera Dinámica Ya Que Puede Ser Variable, en el Ejemplo es con ese ( #Inicio ) pero me pueden llegar direcciones con otros identificadores ( #Matematicas , #SEO , etc... ).

Comment: No utilizo variables, es el propio identificador de la dirección, no lo pongo como variable.
Necesito que lo coja de la dirección variable con ese identificador y en ese momento y no uso variables de tipo GET para acceder a una variable...
Necesito Método de Lectura de la Dirección No Usar Variables...